# What is wrong with URI handling on Linux Mint?

Tags: xfce, locale, unicode, url, xdg

I'm using Linux Mint 17.2 XFCE.

I face very strange problem on my Linux Mint 17.2 XFCE. When I open files, that are located in paths with non-latin names (for example /home/yanpas/Загрузки) I see popup window with error:

[image: screenshot].

The same doesn't happen on Xubuntu 15.04 (it has the same locale parameters (output of `locale` is pretty much the same)). Where can error be hidden? The exo-open version is eqaul on both systems.

```
    $ locale
    LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
    LANGUAGE=
    LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
    LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
    LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
    LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
    LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
    LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
    LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
    LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
    LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
    LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
    LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
    LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
    LC_ALL=
```

To reproduce: open any pdf with non-latin path in qpdfview. Then in qpdfview right-click -> open containing folder (in newer versions file-> open cont. folder). The same happens with exporting to PDF in Libreoffice with tick "open after export". The problem seems to be Mint or/and XFCE-specific.

Comment: This might be a filesystem issue. What are the filesystems on your Mint and Xubuntu systems?

Comment: @KevinVW this is definetely not FS problem, Linux Mint is unable to convert /%D0%97... to /Загрузки . Both systems use ext4 (xubuntu is on virtualbox).

Comment: That's good. If it helps, my locale is en_US.UTF-8 and I can manage paths like Загрузки just fine. Maybe you're missing some character maps in `/usr/share/i18n/charmaps`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is specific to Linux Mint and the source of it was Linux Mint packages.
To fix it type in terminal following line:

`sudo apt-get install exo-utils/trusty libexo-common/trusty libexo-helpers/trusty`

And disable their updates:
`sudo apt-mark hold exo-utils libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers`